# Application.yml is not respected on AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-lambda, serverless, aws-serverless

I'm using [aws-serverless-java-container-spring](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-java-container).

I've upgraded Spring Boot from 2.0.0 to 2.1.8 in my Lambda function.

Now, when I run my lambda I'm facing this error:

```
15:00:31.907 [main] ERROR com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.AwsProxyExceptionHandler - Called exception handler for:
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionOverrideException: Invalid bean definition with name 'handlerExceptionResolver' defined in com.example.cognitouseradd.CognitoUserAddApplication: Cannot register bean definition [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=cognitoUserAddApplication; factoryMethodName=handlerExceptionResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in com.example.cognitouseradd.CognitoUserAddApplication] for bean 'handlerExceptionResolver': There is already [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration; factoryMethodName=handlerExceptionResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class]] bound.
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.registerBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:893)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:274)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:141)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:117)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:327)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:232)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:705)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:131)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91)
at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:171)
at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.spring.SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.handleRequest(SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.java:132)
at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.spring.SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.handleRequest(SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.java:52)
at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.internal.LambdaContainerHandler.proxy(LambdaContainerHandler.java:163)
at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.internal.LambdaContainerHandler.proxyStream(LambdaContainerHandler.java:198)
at com.example.cognitouseradd.StreamLambdaHandler.handleRequest(StreamLambdaHandler.java:34)
at lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader$2.call(EventHandlerLoader.java:888)
at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.startRuntime(AWSLambda.java:293)
at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.<clinit>(AWSLambda.java:64)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at lambdainternal.LambdaRTEntry.main(LambdaRTEntry.java:114)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionOverrideException: Invalid bean definition with name 'handlerExceptionResolver' defined in com.example.cognitouseradd.CognitoUserAddApplication: Cannot register bean definition [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=cognitoUserAddApplication; factoryMethodName=handlerExceptionResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in com.example.cognitouseradd.CognitoUserAddApplication] for bean 'handlerExceptionResolver': There is already [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration; factoryMethodName=handlerExceptionResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class]] bound.
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.registerBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:893)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:274)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:141)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:117)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:327)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:232)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:705)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:131)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91)
at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:171)
at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.spring.SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.handleRequest(SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.java:132)
at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.spring.SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.handleRequest(SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.java:52)
at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.internal.LambdaContainerHandler.proxy(LambdaContainerHandler.java:163)
at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.internal.LambdaContainerHandler.proxyStream(LambdaContainerHandler.java:198)
at com.example.cognitouseradd.StreamLambdaHandler.handleRequest(StreamLambdaHandler.java:34)
at lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader$2.call(EventHandlerLoader.java:888)
at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.startRuntime(AWSLambda.java:293)
at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.<clinit>(AWSLambda.java:64)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at lambdainternal.LambdaRTEntry.main(LambdaRTEntry.java:114)
```

I put application.yml in my resources with this content:

```
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
```

With this, the Spring Boot application runs alright locally but on Lambda it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Were you able to solve it?